# How to set default Xcode company identifier?

Tags: xcode, settings, project, identifier

I think i am going to go nuts if i will continue searching for a solution because it's nowhere to be found.

Xcode sometimes seems to be having a mind of its own... When I am creating a project:

[image: screen shot]

As you can see it greets me with "velvetWeaver" default for my company identifier. I am beating my head against the wall for about three hours now trying to figure out how to change this default...

If anybody knows where this is coming from I will be very grateful.

NOTE: my address Book card has a completely different company name.

---

Comment: don't answer your question in the question. You should write an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was not letting me do that, but I moved it to the answers now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i just experienced stupidity seizure...

Answer to my question:

> Where Xcode picks up company identifier?

**The company identifier is being carried over from whatever previous project you created.**

Somehow this obvious conclusion completely eluded me for past three hours.